# macOS codesign error: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, codesign

I'm having some issues codesigning my code in Jenkins. The config that I have used in the past has never given me any grief but I added 3 new macOS executors yesterday and none of them are working.

The actual error that I get is part of the OpenJDK configure script:

```sh
configure:54803: checking for codesign
configure:55031: result: /usr/bin/codesign
configure:55436: checking if codesign certificate is present
codesign-testfile: errSecInternalComponent
configure:55444: result: no
```

Before running this I have already unlocked the keychain and verified that the keychain contains the certificate.

I am able to SSH into the machine and run this simple script which essentially does the same thing as jenkins:

```sh
security unlock-keychain -p <password> login.keychain-db
rm -rf /Users/jenkins/test && touch /Users/jenkins/test
codesign --sign "Developer ID Application: <name>" /Users/jenkins/test
```

From some research the only other thing I've seen is about setting the key-partition-list correctly which I've already done:

```sh
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k <password> /Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

Any help here would be much appreciated! I feel like I've tried every fix suggested out there so I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After a huge amount of head bashing I finally found out that the keychains (when created via cli) have a timeout of 5 minutes which explains why they failed at the configure stage. The fix was to run the following command:

```sh
security set-keychain-settings login.keychain-db
```

Comment: where do you added this code? I also face issue with Jenkins, so do I have to add in jenkins script? or just run into the Jenkins machne?